# What is best practice for finding dynamic libraries for extension modules.?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, cmake, setuptools

I have a python module that relies on C++ extensions that are built using CMake. There are multiple ways that I can build these C++ extensions. For instance, I have C extensions for python2.7 and C extensions for python 3.6. Because I use CMake to separate my build files from my source files I have the problem of needing to locate the correct binaries at runtimes.

Consider a minimal module setup:

```
* setup.py
* CMakeLists.txt
* src/
    * mymodule.c
* mymodule/
    * __init__.py
* build27/
    * CMakeCache.txt
    * lib
        * libmymodule.so
* build36/
    * CMakeCache.txt
    * lib
        * libmymodule.so
* build27_debug/
    * CMakeCache.txt
    * lib
        * libmymodule.so
```

Solutions I've seen before usually end up copying build files into the source repository, which seems like an anti-pattern to me.

What are best practices for allowing `__init__.py` and `setup.py` to find the correct version of the dynamic libraries? Is it possible to keep the build files separate from the source files?

---

So Far:

The only solution I've come up with so far is to copy the python source files into the appropriate build directory and from there I will have control over what the directory names are.

However, because I'm developing the module I really want to either run `python setup.py develop` or `pip install -e .` to install the module in editable/develop mode. That way when I make changes to `__init__.py`, I see them immediately. If I copy the python module to the build directory I cannot achieve this behavior.

I've also considered using symlinks, but sadly I've been unable to get this to work on windows.

---

Additional information:

I'm running several virtualenvs that correspond to the build folders I've created.

The real repo I'm trying to do this with is my fork of [FLANN](https://github.com/Erotemic/flann) (which is setup in a way that is a bit more complicated than this minimal example)